# Where is the best place to remove Observer from Notification Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I think that should be here:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc removeObserver:self];

}
```

or maybe in `-dealloc`.

Both sound strange to me so I´m not totally sure of it.

First, in my AppDelegate I´m listening to a Remote Notification Via Parse

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

    NSString * urlToGo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSLog (@"Recibo notificación con paremetro url: %@", urlToGo);


    NSNotification *note = [NSNotification
                            notificationWithName:PUSH_NOTIFICATION
                            object:self
                            userInfo:userInfo];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:note];

}
```

and in myViewController
    - (void) viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

```
    _lastMenuSelected=menu1;

    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    [center addObserverForName:PUSH_NOTIFICATION
                        object:nil
                         queue:mainQueue
                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                     // Save in property to load parameter in prepareForSegure
                        _urlToLoadFromPush = urlToGoReceivedFromPush;
                    [self showPush:self];

                    }];


}



- (void)showPush:(id)sender {

    PushViewController * pushViewController=(PushViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PushId"];

    pushViewController.url  = _urlToLoadFromPush;
    UINavigationController* nVC=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pushViewController];
    [self presentViewController:nVC animated:YES completion:^{
        //[_delegate logout];
    }];


}
```

Comment: Where did you add the observer? Remove it from the opposite method.

Comment: rmaddy is right, but just in case you didn't type this code as an example you're calling super viewDidDisappear from viewWillDisappear

Comment: Why is there code for an app delegate and a view controller in the same file? Or is the posted code form different classes? If so, make that clear.

Comment: Right, I have edited the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you seem to be adding the observer in the `viewDidLoad` method (which is only called once as of iOS 6), you should remove the observer in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: The point is that it should react in both, background and visible, as we are talking about push notifications, and as well if the notification arrives when the user is using the app

Comment: The view controller must be removed when it is deallocated otherwise your app will crash if a notification comes in after the view controller is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Don't remove the observer in viewWillDisappear beacause generally we require to post the notification when the view is in the stack but not appearing. So always try to remove the observers in -(void)dealloc with the name of observer.